# Complex anti-join apparently returns rows that aren't empty in table 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables ...

```
CREATE TABLE segmented_text (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    hash        BYTEA  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    text        TEXT   NOT NULL,
    segmented   JSONB
);
CREATE TABLE translations (
    lang TEXT NOT NULL,
    word TEXT NOT NULL,
    engl TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (lang, word)
);
```

The JSON structure in the 'segmented' field always has this format:

```
[ { "l":"it", "t":["aforismi", "un", "gatto", "migliora", "il", "muro", ...] },
  { "l":"fr", "t":["beaujolais", "bordeaux", "borgogna", "champagne", ...] },
  ... ]
```

The client application is trying to scan `segmented_text` for every word in each language that doesn't already have an entry in the `translations` table.  It will look these words up in an external language-to-English dictionary service and insert the results into the `translations` table, essentially as follows (Python/psycopg2):

```
cur = db.cursor()
# see below
cur.execute("[get all the untranslated words]", (can_translate,))

engl = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for lang, word in cur:
    if word not in english[lang]:
        english[lang][word] = get_translation(lang, word)

for lang, words in english.items():
    for word, engl in words.items():
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO translations VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                    (lang, word, engl))
db.commit()
```

My question has to do with the "[get all the untranslated words]" query.  I have been testing two variations.  (The query parameter, `can_translate`, is an array of all the language codes that the dictionary service offers.)

This version has acceptable performance, taking ~10 minutes to scan the entire `segmented_text` table, *but* it seems to be incorrect.

```
SELECT w.lang, w.word
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
     chunk->>'l' AS lang,
     jsonb_array_elements_text(chunk->'t') AS word
  FROM (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(segmented) AS chunk
    FROM segmented_text 
    WHERE segmented IS NOT NULL) _
  WHERE chunk->>'l' = ANY(%s)) w
LEFT JOIN translations t ON w.lang = t.lang AND w.word = t.word
WHERE t.word IS NULL;
```

The problem with this is, about one in 200 of the subsequent INSERTs throws a constraint violation, claiming that the pair (lang, word) already exists in the translations table.  The application takes care not to insert any such pair more than once, so it must be that the anti-join in this query is somehow not filtering out all the words that have already been translated.

The only other clue I've got is that this adjustment eliminates the problem -- the only difference is the position of the `DISTINCT` modifier.  However, the price for that is completely unacceptable performance; it takes upwards of six hours to scan the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.lang, w.word
FROM (
  SELECT 
     chunk->>'l' AS lang,
     jsonb_array_elements_text(chunk->'t') AS word
  FROM (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(segmented) AS chunk
    FROM segmented_text 
    WHERE segmented IS NOT NULL) _
  WHERE chunk->>'l' = ANY(%s)) w
LEFT JOIN translations t ON w.lang = t.lang AND w.word = t.word
WHERE t.word IS NULL;
```

When I do small spot-checks, both queries *seem* to be doing the Right Thing, but the full-scale operation must be screwing up somehow.  (To give an idea of the scale of the problem, there are ~200,000 words in 80 languages needing translated, and ~11,000,000 words already in the `translations` table.)

I could paper over the problem on the insertion side, but the dictionary service costs me money on a per-word basis, so I would rather fix the initial query so it reliably only returns words that haven't already been translated.

Answer (score 0):

You're join logic seems sound (given that word is declared not null) so the only thing that I can see being possible is that the join logic is failing.  For that to happen when the value is actually there you probably has to do with the type (or contents) of the data in the first part of the query.  You are doing some fancy json stuff there and the result might not 'equal' the text values in the translation table.  Then when you go to insert them, they are coerced/converted into the right type (if you haven't already handled that) and match the existing values.

I've seen this kind of thing when there are CHAR types joined against VARCHAR types.  You might want to check for the usual suspects like whitespace or unprintable characters in your JSON in these offending words.

Comment: The inner query on the left side of the LEFT JOIN (the one given the shortname `w`) produces two TEXT columns.  Is your advice still the same?

Comment: There are three possible things here.  1. Concurrency i.e. something changed while it was running.  2. There's a bug in the DB.  3. The left side of your join is presenting something that is different than what you are inserting.  I got the feeling you ruled #1 out but that's something to consider if not.  #2 seems very unlikely.  You wouldn't be the only person to have this issue.  So that leaves us with 3.  Have you checked for extra characters (like trailing spaces) in the JSON for the words that are failing?  Are you doing any normalization on the words (e.g. lower, trim) before inserting?

Comment: I have edited the question with new information (which I didn't have yesterday) -- I found a modification to the SELECT that eliminates the problem, but at terrible cost.

Comment: Ah, so it was actually #1.  You are getting the same words multiple times hence the failure on later attempts.  Is there a reason you are storing the values to search for as JSON?  I would expect that if you put that data in to a proper table with indexes, you would be able to get the distinct set at very little cost.  The other option would be to parse and dedupe outside of the DB.  6 hours seems a like a long time for that so I'm guess the implementation is not optimal.

Comment: Retrieval in the normal case is enormously simplified with the data stored the way it is (i.e. normally applications will pull out the JSON all at once and process it themselves).  In any case I can't afford to change the data model that radically at present.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are doing this all on the DB or outside of the DB.  If you are doing the larger application outside of the DB, what language/tools are you using?

Comment: Python with the psycopg2 client library.  The application code I showed is not the actual application code but it is functionally equivalent.

Comment: Try taking your original query and putting the results into python maps.  You'll get rid of the dupes and it should be reasonably quick.  Even if your average word length is 20 characters, you are only talking about a few million chars.  That's pretty tiny relative to a contemporary system's memory.

Comment: I already do that... AFAICT, it's not that there are duplicates within the result set, it's that some of the results in the result set shouldn't have been returned at all.

Comment: Sorry, something isn't adding up.  How would putting DISTINCT in the query resolve that.  The only thing that accomplishes is to remove duplicates.

Comment: I'm as confused as you are!

Comment: The fact that moving that DISTINCT from the nested query to the outer query changes the behavior indicates that there is something funky about the semantics of the nested query.  I'll hazard a guess that it's related to doing the JSON parsing and that isn't playing nicely with the relational model.  Looking at your SQL, I'm not sure why you need two levels of nesting.  Can you remove the outer most and put the join on the `select chunk->'l'` part?  Also have you tried comparing these results of the two queries on a small result set that contains problematic values?